# How to implement a custom dataset with torchtext v0.9?

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch

I am completely new to torchtext and new to PyTorch in general. I cannot find any tutorials/explanations on how to do so (there is a severe lack of examples right now). My project is on the [SMS  Spam Collection dataset](https://www.dt.fee.unicamp.br/%7Etiago/smsspamcollection).

Answer (score 0):

This could be helpful: https://github.com/pytorch/text/tree/master/examples
Legacy tutorial there teaches most of the things you need to know. In most of the tutorials legacy code is used, but here you can see how to migrate to the new one.
If you want a tutorial : https://youtu.be/KRgq4VnCr7I
This uses the legacy code, but you can fix it using the first source.